# Ajax success event in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails newbe here. I've got links that do ajax query to server:

```
<%= link_to g.name, g, :class => 'link link-to-gallery', :remote => true %>
```

JS view that loads data from partial:

```
$('#content').html('<%= escape_javascript render("layouts/galleries/show") %>');
```

And controller that operates with models and renders html and js:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @galleries = Gallery.all
    @gallery_to_show = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Ajax works fine, but I try to put callback after ajax completed:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $(".link-to-gallery").bind("ajax:complete", function() {
    alert(1)
  });
});
```

and alert never shows. What am I doing wrong? Rails version is 3.2.11, Ruby version is 1.9.3p194

Update: When I'm using this code

```
jQuery(function() {
  $(".link-to-gallery")
    .on("ajax:before", function () {
      alert("before")
    })
    .on("ajax:complete", function() {
      alert("complete")
    });
});
```

"before" alert fires but only once. If I press again I gain nothing. But ajax still works.

Comment: Did you try using `on`, the preferred mechanism in jQuery 1.7+?

Comment: Is your callback code getting overridden by the call in the js view ? 
Also @Dave Newton made a good point.  You should be using `on` instead of `bind` of jquery to handle events.

Comment: Tried this. Same thing as with "bind". But I have some new info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I'm lame but smart enough to fix this. I had these links:

```
<%= link_to g.name, g, :class => 'link link-to-gallery', :remote => true %>
```

in the partial which gets re-rendered after ajax. So the callback functions that were attached to these links were flushed away after ajax. So I put link out of this partial and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your controller method that is not responding the async call with a success status message, 200.

Try this

```rb
def show
  @galleries = Gallery.all
  @gallery_to_show = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { :status => 200 }
    format.js { :status => 200 }
  end
end
```

If that doesn't work, try this.

```rb
def show
  @galleries = Gallery.all
  @gallery_to_show = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { :status => :ok }
    format.js { :status => :ok }
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've never had to manually set an OK response or status.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if Rails by default returns OK status by default. But I know for a fact that `ajax:complete` only executes if OK or Fail status is returned. So can't hurt to try.